# How to get firebase to display a string and not com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference@26621628

Tags: firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, android-jetpack-compose

I'm making an app in kotlin jetpack compose and I want to have a question displayed from a database which is on firestore. And when I try to get a question from the database it displayed something else.

I tried to get a question from the database using the following code

```
`fun Question1Screen (navController: NavController, viewModel: QuestViewModel) {
     var firestore: FirebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    var selectedAnswer by remember { mutableStateOf(-1) }
    val docRef = firestore.collection("D3NhDOEPBdaW8bEUPfjL").document("Question")
    docRef.get()
        .addOnSuccessListener { document ->
            if (document != null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot data: ${document.data}")
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "No such document")
            }
        }
        .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
            Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", exception)
        }
    Column(
        Modifier.padding(16.dp)
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.TopEnd
        ) {
            Text(
                text = viewModel.getQuest().toString()
            )
        }`
```

Code for getQuest:

```
 fun getQuest() {
        reset()
        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
                questRepository.getQuest()
            } catch (ex: QuestRepository.QuestRetrievalError) {
                val errorMsg = "Something went wrong while retrieving quest.\n" +
                        "It could be that you still need to install your own google-services.json file from Firestore."
                Log.e(TAG, ex.message ?: errorMsg)
                _errorText.value = errorMsg
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

I was expected to see an question but instead I see the following

`com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference@26621628`

Reset function:

```
  fun reset() {
        _errorText.value = ""
        questRepository.reset()
    }
```

getQuest:

```
   suspend fun getQuest() {

try {
    //firestore has support for coroutines via the extra dependency we've added :)
    withTimeout(5_000) {
        val data = questDocument
            .get()
            .await()

        val question = data.getString("Question").toString()
        val answer = data.getString("answer").toString()

        _quest.value = Quest(question, answer)
    }
} catch (e: Exception) {
    throw QuestRetrievalError("Retrieval-firebase-task was unsuccessful")
}
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot. Besides that, please also show the `getQuest()` that exists inside your ViewModel class.

Comment: Edit: added screenshot of database and added code of getquest

Comment: Please also show us what `reset()` does and what exactly the `questRepository.getQuest()` function looks like in the repository.

Comment: Edit: added code of reset() and added code of questRepository.getQuest()

Comment: Aside from my answer, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-cloud-firestore-using-get-bf03b6ee4953) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/CloudFirestore/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the problems in your code lies in the following lines of code:

```
val docRef = firestore.collection("D3NhDOEPBdaW8bEUPfjL").document("Question")
```

Seeing your database screenshot, you have a collection called "quest" and a document that has an ID of "D3NhDOEPBdaW8bEUPfjL". On the other hand, "Question" is a field within a document. If you want to read the value of the "Question" field, you have to create a reference that points to the document that contains that field, attach a listener and then get the data out of the [DocumentSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot) object. In code, it will look as simple as:

```
val questRef = Firebase.firestore.collection("quest")
questRef.document("D3NhDOEPBdaW8bEUPfjL").get().addOnCompleteListener { task ->
    if (task.isSuccessful) {
        val document = task.result
        if (document.exists()) {
            val question = document.getString("Question")
            Log.d("TAG", question)
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", "The document doesn't exist.")
        }
    } else {
        task.exception?.message?.let {
            Log.d("TAG", it) //Never ignore potential errors!
        }
    }
}
```

The result in the logcat will be:

```
What is 45 x 12
```

If you want to implement the above code using MVVM, then you have to move the request to Firestore in a function inside a repository class, call the method from within a ViewModel class using a viewModelScope and then collection the result and pass it further to the UI.

Comment: Okay thanks, so now it says kotlin.unit but in the log it makes the question What is 45 x 12

Comment: As long as you get in the logcat `What is 45 x 12`, it means that the code above works and you can read the desired that. This also means that you can also propagate that result to your composable functions.

Comment: Since the solution above works, but you're having a hard time propagating the data to the views, I recommend posting a new question, here on StackOverflow, using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with everything you have tried. In this way, I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: Can I help you with other information regarding the initial question?

Comment: Okay, thank you for the help I will try using its own MCVE and I dont have any other questions!